# react videojs chromecast not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, chromecast, video.js

React does not try to implement videojs chromecast plugin.

I refer to this site: https://github.com/benjipott/video.js-chromecast

Thank you.

*-- my code --*

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import videojs from 'videojs-chromecast';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    videojs('test',{
      chromecast:{
         appId:'APP-ID'
      }
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App" >
        <video id="test" autoplay="autoplay" width="640" height="360" controls="controls">
          <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/ED_1280.mp4"
            
          />
        </video>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

*-- error massage --*
[image]

Comment: Why are you using componentDidMount? Is there any documentation on how to implement this in react? Also it seems that something is undefined and it could be that you are not making a reference to your videojs in a global variable in your componentDidMount() that can be accessed through out the app.js

Comment: Did you find the solution on this? I met the same behavior ((